# Multi object SSS

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, subsurface-scattering

So, it seems like multi object SSS in Blender Cycles is not possible, and therefore, when 2 or more meshes with a material that has SSS intersect, it will make an ugly dark line at the intersection.

Are there any workarounds to this?
Could it somehow be fixed with compositing?

The desired effect is smooth, seamless transition from one mesh/material to another mesh/material, with SSS enabled for both.

[image]

Comment: The abstraction of Surface, SSS, and Volume Shaders make this impossible, since the SSS is only simulated per surface entry point. Did you try joining both objects and mixing both shaders with a ramp?

Comment: Or is your problem [Overlapping surfaces](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/132035/30849)?